# Javascript missing semicolon, where?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am using vb.net with javascript. Whenever I click a link on page 1, it loads and opens page 2. As part of this, in the page_load I have a bit of code which registers a javascript function as below:

```
   Private Sub regjs()
        Dim requesttype = "xx"
        Dim url As String = "page.aspx?rtype=" & requesttype & "&claimid="

        Dim s As New StringBuilder
        s.Append("<script type=""text/javaScript"">")
        s.Append("var r = new Object();" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("if (window.returnValue == 'undefined') { window.returnValue = ''; }" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("function vt(param) { " & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("if (param !== null) {" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        ***s.Append("var jurl = '" & url & "'")
        s.Append("param;" & ControlChars.CrLf)***
        s.Append("var r = window.showModalDialog(jurl,'','dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px;resizable:no');" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("</script>")

        If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("js") Then
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "js", s.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am getting an error saying there is a missing semicolon when the page attempts to load. The error is occuring on the s.Append("param;" * ControlChars.CrLf) line saying there is a missing ";". Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong? (I am trying to construct a url with a variable as a query string value).

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1):

That code outputs the following string:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">var r = new Object();
if (window.returnValue == 'undefined') { window.returnValue = ''; }
function vt(param) { 
if (param !== null) {
var jurl = 'page.aspx?rtype=xx&claimid='param;
var r = window.showModalDialog(jurl,'','dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px;resizable:no');
}
}
</script>
```

As you can see, this line is invalid:

```
var jurl = 'page.aspx?rtype=xx&claimid='param;
```

I suspect that you intended to do a string concatenation there.

Also, it's worth mentioning that you should just use `StringBuilder.AppendLine` rather than `Append` with `ControlChars.CrLf`.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a variable you need to end the statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.Append("var jurl = '" & url & "'")
s.Append("param;" & ControlChars.CrLf)
```

builds the code

```
var jurl = 'page.aspx?rtype=xx&claimId='param;
                                       ^
```

The string (and the statement) ends at the indicated point, but there is no semicolon.

One assumes you meant to add the `param` to the end of the string, in which case you are missing a `+`.